# Search all Inputs with specific class - Numeric Only

Tags: jquery, alert, numeric

On my page I have an input field with the class of 'Update'

This input field can be duplicated, so there may be anything from 1 - xxx entries.

On form submission using jquery, I want to check these input fields only contains numeric values. If not issue an alert and if possible highlight the invalid field !

So far I've got this but it's not working.

```
$('#frm').on('submit',function(e) {
    if (!$('[class^="Update"]').numeric()) { 
     alert('Numeric Values Only'); return false; 
    };
e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Any idea how to do this ?

Thanks

UPDATE

I've tried:

```
    if (!$('[class^="Update"]').isNumeric) { 
        alert('Numeric Values Only');
    };
```

That seems to alert regardless of the value in the field.

The input field is :

`<input class="Update" name="ID[]" type="text" id="LocationID"/>`

I've also tried:

```
$(".Update").each(function() {
            if ($(this).val().isNumeric) console.log( $(this).val() )
        });
```

This writes out to the console regardless of the value being a number or not.

I only want the input fields with a class of Update to be able to contain numbers, no letters or other characters.

Comment: You seem to be calling `.numeric()`. Does that not produce any errors..? Perhaps try `.isNumeric()`.

Comment: What's not working (what's expected vs. what is happening, what are the errors)? Can you post the HTML as well? those are probably the reason why you have downvotes.

Comment: @Rocket I'm surprised that the console log work sinc `String.isNumeric === undefined`... Anyway, try : `$.isNumeric(this.value)`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon that seems to have sorted it. If you want to add it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks